# sed: how to locate between two ranges (Numeric)

Tags: sed, match

Is it possible to use Sed to locate between two IP Addresses?

Currently am doing:

```
sed '/85.159.56/s/$/ ---  API SYSTEMS/'
```

But i have a specific range i want to have print out next to it 
(This is part of a bigger script)

For example:

```
sed '/192.200.160.0 - 192.200.191.255/s/$/ ---  APIv2 SYSTEMS/'
```

I know this is not the correct format. 
But ideally i want Sed to locate the string between these two ranges
Then print out next to it ---  APIv2 SYSTEMS/

I have tried many ways and unable to accomplish, Making me think `Sed` not the tool for the job.

Comment: `sed` deals with "strings" of "characters" pretty well, but doesn't do very well with interpreting the semantic information in those strings (i.e. the numeric value of a sequence of digits, or an IP address). You would probably be better using a slightly bigger hammer, like `python` or `perl` or even `awk`.

Comment: agree with above, but if you can formulate a regular expression (or several) that capture the range, then you can use `sed`. Maybe `/192.200.1[6-9][0-1].[0-2][0-9][0-9]/` for starters. Yes, I realize that it will accept values that are not valid IP addresses and valid addresses that are may not belong in your range. Just an idea. You'll have to decide if the maintenance problems save you time versus figuring out a proper solutions with other tools. Good luck!